# Google map API v2 J2ME

Tags: google-maps, java-me

Hi everybody im a beginner in J2ME developpement and i created a little j2me application that supposed to allow me to locate places  based on an address that i have to enter in a enter in a TextField  so i made this piece of code based on a tutorial a from jappit.com but when i launch the application the screen is blocked on loading and i get this error in the console:

"Uncaught exception java/lang/NumberFormatException: Sorry... body { font-family: verdana."

and this is the code :

```
import com.jappit.midmaps.googlemaps.GoogleMaps;
import com.jappit.midmaps.googlemaps.GoogleMapsCoordinates;
import com.jappit.midmaps.googlemaps.GoogleMapsGeocoder;
import com.jappit.midmaps.googlemaps.GoogleMapsGeocoderHandler;
import com.jappit.midmaps.googlemaps.GoogleMapsMarker;
import com.jappit.midmaps.googlemaps.GoogleStaticMap;
import com.jappit.midmaps.googlemaps.GoogleStaticMapHandler;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Alert;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.AlertType;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Canvas;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Command;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.CommandListener;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Display;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Displayable;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Form;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Graphics;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.List;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.TextField;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Ticker;
import javax.microedition.midlet.MIDlet;
import javax.microedition.midlet.MIDletStateChangeException;


public class MapMidlet extends MIDlet implements CommandListener{


    TextField searchbox = new TextField("Address","Enter your address here",100,TextField.ANY);
        Form menu = new Form("Search Menu");
        List type = new List("Type",List.EXCLUSIVE);
        Command search = new Command("Search",Command.OK,0);
        Command Exit = new Command("exit",Command.EXIT,1);
    Display display = Display.getDisplay(this);
    Ticker ti = new Ticker("Find me If you can !");
        Alert alert = new Alert("Please enter an address","address is missing", null, AlertType.ERROR);
     String adress;  
    public MapMidlet() {
    }

    protected void destroyApp(boolean unconditional)
             {

    }

    protected void pauseApp() {

    }

    protected void startApp()  {
      adress=searchbox.getString();
          menu.setCommandListener(this);
          menu.append(searchbox);
          menu.addCommand(search);
          menu.addCommand(Exit);
          display.setCurrent(menu);



    //display.setCurrent(new  MapCanvas(this));

    }

    public void commandAction(Command c, Displayable d) {





        if(c==search)
        {



        display.setCurrent(new MapCanvas(this));}



        else
         {notifyDestroyed();}


    }



    public class MapCanvas extends Canvas implements GoogleStaticMapHandler, GoogleMapsGeocoderHandler
{
    GoogleMaps gMaps = null;

    GoogleStaticMap map = null;

     String API_KEY = "AIzaSyBe1yXRcCXWQB_6ReSGbf0lH8XVwTvNpSQ";
    MapMidlet mid;
    public MapCanvas(MapMidlet mid)
    {

        this.mid=mid;
        gMaps = new GoogleMaps(API_KEY);

        map = gMaps.createMap(getWidth(), getHeight(), GoogleStaticMap.FORMAT_PNG);

        //map.setHandler(this);
        //map.setCenter(new GoogleMapsCoordinates(36.8189700,10.1657900));
                //map.setZoom(15);

        //map.update();

        GoogleMapsGeocoder geocoder = gMaps.createGeocoder();

        geocoder.setHandler(this);

        geocoder.geocodeAddress(adress);
    }

    protected void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        map.draw(g, 0, 0, Graphics.TOP | Graphics.LEFT);
    }

    public void GoogleMapsGeocodeError(String address, int errorCode, String errorDescription)
    {
        System.out.println("Geocode error: " + errorCode + ", " + errorDescription);
    }
    public void GoogleMapsGeocodeSuccess(String address, GoogleMapsCoordinates coordinates, int accuracy)
    {
        map.setCenter(coordinates);

        map.addMarker(new GoogleMapsMarker(coordinates));

        map.setZoom(accuracy);

        map.update();
    }
    public void GoogleStaticMapUpdateError(GoogleStaticMap map, int errorCode, String errorMessage)
    {
        System.out.println("map error: " + errorCode + ", " + errorMessage);
    }
    public void GoogleStaticMapUpdated(GoogleStaticMap map)
    {
        System.out.println("map loaded");

        repaint();
    }

}


}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Wrong CLDC version can result in a `NumberFormatException`. For example, if your project is set to CLDC 1.0 (which doesn't allow floats), and you use floats anyway. Or if your project is set to CLDC 1.1 while using libraries that was coded for CLDC 1.0.

Comment: Thank you mr_loup for the reply , i tried both of them but i still get the error :<

Comment: just develop it in Android, is a best option